# What is the correct type for this handler

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, eslint

I´m having trouble in "picking" the correct type for this function. It is an async handler for express js. The project uses typescript and eslint for linting with a few rules

```
export function asyncHandler(
  handler: any
): (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => void {
  return function (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): void {
    Promise.resolve(handler(req, res, next)).catch(err => {
      next(err);
    });
  };
}
```

If I change the handler to `handler: RequestHandler` the eslint shows this error

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `RequestHandler` interface expect the function to return void, but your `post` function returns a Promise, hence the error.

Here is the interface definition of `RequestHandler`

```
export interface RequestHandler<
    P = ParamsDictionary,
    ResBody = any,
    ReqBody = any,
    ReqQuery = ParsedQs,
    Locals extends Record<string, any> = Record<string, any>
> {
    // tslint:disable-next-line callable-types (This is extended from and can't extend from a type alias in ts<2.2)
    (
        req: Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery, Locals>,
        res: Response<ResBody, Locals>,
        next: NextFunction,
    ): void;
}
```

In my opinion, you can keep using `any` since it's one of those edge cases in which you don't have to be too strict in your types constraint. If you still want to use a type, you could generate your own interface of a request handler.

Using this interface, would remove the linter error:

```
interface AsyncRequestHandler {
  (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction): Promise<any>;
}
```